# Manter histórico da branch ao mover ou renomear pasta

Tags: visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server

Tenho necessidade de reorganizar uma estrutura em que os códigos-fonte das minhas aplicações são mantidos, porém, quando faço a movimentação da *branch* para uma nova pasta, seu histórico de modificações é perdido.

Como posso mover ou renomear uma *branch* dentro do meu repositório sem perder o histórico de modificações?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode renomear usando -m.

1) git checkout "branch"

2) git branch -m "rename_branch"

Um abraço

Obs: Me deixe saber se isso lhe ajudou.

Comment: Infelizmente não estou usando o git como repositório. Eu consigo mover e renomear a branch, porém quando faço o commit, o histórico das modificações é perdido.